# Invalid unicode characters in docker for shared network volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am writing a program in python using docker and wanted access to a network shared volume. my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    testpathdocker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - TechPlots:/opt/app/static
volumes:
    TechPlots:
        driver_opts:
            type: "cifs"
            o: "user=alg,password=123"
            device: "//192.168.154.137/share/TechPlots"
```

the file names in the shared folder are in Persian.

When the container is running, instead of the actual file names, their names in the container appear as invalid characters like question marks such as `????.jpg`. I simply list the directory by python using `os.getdir(PATH_TO_SHARE)`. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the Python code, is the file name a valid Unicode string (for example, can you check the `ord()` of one of the characters) and it's just printing wrong?  Can you edit the question to include the relevant Python code?

Comment: PATH_TO_SHARE is all in english, but the files in the folder are in persian, which is a valid Unicode string. The python code is just a one line code `os.getdir(PATH_TO_SHARE)`. I tried the exact same code in venv without docker and that worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I copied those files on my local computer and shared them with docker using docker volume and worked fine.

So the source of the problem is the way `cifs` works. Apparently, you should use `iocharset=utf8` in the options to read Unicode filenames correctly from the network. So I changed the volume section into:

```
volumes:
    TechPlots:
        driver_opts:
            type: "cifs"
            o: "iocharset=utf8,user=alg,password=123"
            device: "//192.168.154.137/share/TechPlots"
```